# Datastore Category vs. String: what is the difference?

Tags: google-app-engine, types, google-cloud-datastore

Looking at Category it seems that it is basically a String. I fail to see any advantages of using Category over String.
What is the difference, and why would I use Category instead of String?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `entity.to_xml()`, a category will come back as an [Atom category element](http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/#category).

Beyond that, it's just a string.